# Importing unknown file from a folder

Tags: python, windows

Hello (sorry for my bad English)

I am working on a project and there's a folder in which there are  many py files ( I don't know their name)
And I want to import everything from everyfile in that folder ...

Like

```
From folder import every flie
From every file import *
```

This might look stupid as I'm new to python

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You can use `importlib`.  First find all of the `.py` files in your folder.  Then use `importlib` to import them.

Comment: Out of interest, what is the application where you would want to do this?

Comment: The magic in python: A **package** is basically a directory with Python files and a file with the name __init__.py. This means that every directory inside of the Python path, which contains a file named __init__.py, will be treated as a package by Python. Learn more about [Modules and packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)

Comment: I'm working on a chat app and in that I have my client.py and chats (folder) and in that folder every chat has its own file and in those files I have stored messages in a list and using for loop i can load that messages @niko pasanen

Comment: Ah, so did I understand correctly that those "unknown files" you want to "import" contain stored messages?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The name of the python file will be in the editor you are using, so just call each file name and import everything:

```
folder
├── everyfile
│   ├── many.py
│   ├── files.py
```

```
from many import *
from files import *
```

Not the best practice but it should work. Or:

```
from folder.everyfile.many import *
```

Comment: the files will be randomly generated while the user runs the program to store different data, that's why i said unknown files